# Giving a unique identifier to every execution in R

Tags: r

Can anyone please tell me how to assign a unique value to a result set every time its executed ? As displayed in table below, a entry should be added in front of every record and this entry should be same for all the result set that has been obtained during a single execution. The purpose of this to extract the all records in future by just giving a short statement like (where Unique ID = A_Ground_01). Thanks

```
    User      DateTime   Latitude Longitude    Floor     **Unique ID** 
1     A      2017-06-15  47.29404  5.010650    Ground     A_Ground_01
2     A      2017-06-15  47.29403  5.010634    Ground     A_Ground_01
3     A      2017-06-15  47.29403  5.010668    Ground     A_Ground_02
4     A      2017-06-15  47.29403  5.010663    Ground     A_Ground_02
```

Comment: Why the two first rows are getting same unique ID? Based on what criterion you would like to have the **Unique ID** produced?

Comment: Unique ID is based on the execution. You can suppose that after two executions of a same R program we have two different Unique IDs.

Comment: which/what R program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With not knowing anything about your initial dataframe, or the function being executed I might recommend something similar to the following.

In this example I'll assume you have a main dataframe we'll call `df.main` and some new data you will be binding to the main dataframe, we'll call `df.newdata`

Create a column in your main dataframe called `df.main$ExecID` that will contain integer values.

Run whatever your function is and assign `df.newdata$ExecID <- max(df.main$ExecID) + 1`

Generate the unique id using `df.newdata$UniqueID <- paste(df.newdata$User, df.newdata$Floor, df.newdata$ExecID, sep = "_")`

Then run `rbind(df.main, df.newdata)`

To provide a better solution for your specific situation, we really would need to see example code of how your script is written.

Comment: Thank you so much Matt. That's what I wanted.